# Permissions to different roles in Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating an authentication system for my Django web-app. This is my model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    total_earnings = models.IntegerField(default="0")
    month_earnings = models.IntegerField(default="0")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Clase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    counter = models.IntegerField(default="6")
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='english')
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to give different permissions and features to teachers and students, but I have no clue on how. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please fix your title, currently it doesn't reflect your question at all

Comment: Try https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the default authentication and permission mechanism of Django. You just need to extend `User` model.

```
   class Teacher(User):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        total_earnings = models.IntegerField(default="0")
        month_earnings = models.IntegerField(default="0")

   class Student(User):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

You can then create a `Student` and `Teacher` object with appropriate permissions as the same as `User`. It will also create an `User` object. Then, you can access permission as you access on `User` instance.

```
     teacher.get_all_permissions() # returns permissions of a teacher
     student.get_all_permissions() # returns permissions of a student
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know you could do that, this opens up tons of possibilities. Happy new year.

Comment: Happy new year too